# A complex rational function which maps an arc of unit circle in to unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z)=\dfrac{z(z-a)}{(z-b)(z-c)(z-d)}$$ be a complex rational function and let $S=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$ be the unit circle.

> My question:
>   For which (non-zero complex numbers) $a,b,c$ and $d$ there exist an arc $C$ of $S$ such that $f(C)\subseteq S$ ?

Comment: If a=b=c=D=0, f(S)=S

Comment: It looks pretty hopeless in its current form!  Try the Cayley transform and switch to the upper half-plane; then you're looking for it to be real on an interval.  Yes, this will make it much easier...

Comment: If you have even one of $a,b,c,d$ non-zero, any curve $f(C)$ won't even *be* a circular arc. You can show that by looking at $\Re(f)$ and $\Im(f)$ and their corresponding trigonometric form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\bar f(z) = z(z-\bar a)/(z- \bar b)(z- \bar c)(z- \bar d)$.

If $|z|=1$, then $\bar z = z^{-1}$, and so $\overline {f(z)} = \bar f(z^{-1})$, and finally $|f(z)|^2 = f(z)\bar f(z^{-1})$.

Your hypothesis says that $f(z)\bar f(z^{-1}) = 1$ is true on a tiny arc on the unit circle, so it is true on all of $\Bbb C$ (as a corollary, the whole unit circle is sent inside the unit circle, not just a tiny arc).

Rewriting the identity, you get $(z-a)(z^{-1}-\bar a) = (z-b)(z^{-1}-\bar b)(z-c)(z^{-1}-\bar c)(z-d)(z^{-1}-\bar d)$.

After multiplying by $z^3$ you get the equality of two polynomials $z^2(z-a)(1-\bar a z) = (z-b)(1- \bar b z)(z-c)(1- \bar c z)(z-d)(1- \bar d z)$.

By looking at the coefficients of $z^0,z^1$ and $z^2$ this implies that two of $b,c,d$ have to be $0$, and the third has to be equal to $a$, so $f(z) = z^{-1}$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, you can directly calculate the corresponding trigonometric forms of $f$ by substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$. You'll get, then:

$$\Re(f)=\frac{2bcd\cos(\theta)^2-\cos(\theta)bcda+2\cos(\theta)^2a-b\cos(\theta)a-c\cos(\theta)a-d\cos(\theta)a-bc\cos(\theta)-bd\cos(\theta)-cd\cos(\theta)+abc+abd+acd-bcd-\cos(\theta)-a+b+c+d}{(2\cos(\theta)b-b^2-1)(2\cos(\theta)c-c^2-1)(2\cos(\theta)d-d^2-1)}$$

and

$$\Im(f)=-\frac{\sin(\theta)(-2\cos(\theta)bcd+abcd+2a\cos(\theta)-ab-ac-ad+bc+bd+cd-1)}{(2\cos(\theta)b-b^2-1)(2\cos(\theta)c-c^2-1)(2\cos(\theta)d-d^2-1)}$$

Now, I don't know what the above polar expressions describe, but they sure as heck don't describe any circular arc, no matter the $\theta$.

If you kill all the parameters $a,b,c,d$ however, the above reduce to (the obvious otherwise, as per vvnitram's comment):

$$\Re(f)=\cos(\theta)$$

$$\Im(f)=-\sin(\theta)$$

which are the parametric form of the inversion map:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$

Extending the result a bit to move you towards the direction your instructor is hinting at with this problem, you may want to try the general maps, for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$:

$$f_\lambda(z)=\lambda\cdot z^k$$

It would be instructive otherwise to check whether these satisfy the requirements of your problem (Hint: some of them do. Which ones? Are these which do the only ones?)